# When does the last victim die

Tags: plot-explanation, angel-heart

At the end of *Angel Heart*, when Harold finally makes the terrible discovery that he and John Favorite are the same person and that he had killed all those people himself, Harold has a flashback about killing Epiphany (among other people). He returns to the hotel room and finds she is indeed dead. When most of the characters die, there is a fan spinning backwards, but in Epiphany's case this occurs during the infamous sex scene and she is shown alive afterwards.

Harold didn't know about her death up to this point nor did we as the viewers, but are there any hints as to when it had actually happened?

Answer (score 1):

When Epiphany has stayed over in Angel's hotel room, the morning after they have sex, and after he's talked to the local police, she's taking a bath. He asks her about the tune she's singing, she tells him it's one from Johnny Favorite. Then she asks him if he's okay and he says yes. The scene ends with him staring into the mirror he smashed the night before.

The next scene he's out in the city, and doesn't return until the end of the movie.

So it's reasonable to assume it happens right after that stare into the broken mirror.